# Best Way to get kwargs in a class based view?

Tags: python, django

I have a class based Django view:

```
class LocationView(TemplateView):
```

I have defined a named parameter in my url dispatcher:

```
url(r'^locations/(?P<id>\d+)/$', LocationView.as_view(), name="location")
```

I know I can access my `id` parameter in a class method like `get_context_data`, where I can pass in **kwargs to the method itself. However, I'd kind of like to be able to access the parameters within just the class itself, as there is some data I grab from an API that will be used in different capacities in different methods throughout the class. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: "within the class itself", which is where? In which method do you wish to access `id`?

Answer (score 4):

You can do `self.kwargs` in any method that you use that is run after dispatch() is called for the class based view.

If you are doing a detail view for a model, like it seems you are doing, you should probably use one of the generic class based views which will do this for you.

Why don't you try the following:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class LocationView(DetailView):
  queryset = LocationModel.objects.all()
  template_name = 'location_of_detail_template.html'
```

Then update your urls.py file and change the name of the regex group from id to pk to make it all work automatically.